# При передачи переменной в layout на хостинге выдает ошибку

Tags: php, yii2

Ошибка появляется из контроллера, когда передаю в `layout` переменную с моделью контактной формы, во вьюхе получаю ее `<? $model = $this->params['model']; ?>` В виджете `Modal` использую `ActiveForm` и когда в формирую:

```
<?= $forms->field($model, 'name')->textInput() ?>
```

то на локальной машине в `OpenServer` все работает нормально, а на хостинге выдает ошибку:

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException 
Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on null
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. Вы то хоть сами поняли, что написали?

Comment: Покажите, как Вы передаёте модель контактной формы в layout.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag

```
<?php $model = $this->params['model']; ?>
```